# Оплата ПО платежному поручению или оплата платежным поручением?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно писать?
"Оплата задолженности произведена **по** платежному поручению" (с предлогом "**по"**)
или
"Оплата задолженности произведена платежным поручением"?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь все зависит от того, о чем идет речь.

Банк переводит деньги на **ПО** вашему платежному поручению (поэтому оно и называется поручением: вы **поручаете** банку перевести деньги).

В свою очередь вы производите оплату, поручая банку выполнить это действие, т.е. вы даете банку **поручение** (производите **оплату платежным поручением**).

Хотя в реальной жизни оба варианта часто используют в одних и тех же контекстах (порой не всегда обоснованно).